# How to parse the below xml code?

Tags: java, xml

I have sale tag as child node that exists for multiple times but in that Employee tag doesn't exists for all sale tag.need to parse this xml.Got Null pointer exception when there is no employee tag.How to parse this xml even if some child tag name doesn't exists?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <Transactions>
      <DocumentInfo TransferType="Transactions" Copyright="2010, Hectronic GmbH" CreatedBy="HecPoll">
       <CreateDate Year="2011" Month="7" Day="13"/>
       <CreateTime Hour="6" Minute="0" Second="16"/>
      </DocumentInfo>
      <DocumentData>
      <Sale RcpNum="151" Amount="228.760" Station="1" Customer="000003" Terminal="1">
        <Date Year="2011" Month="07" Day="12"/>
        <Time Hour="07" Minute="23" Second="00"/>
        <ArticleSale Quantity="6.020" SglPriceAsSold="38.000" SglPriceAsStored="38.000" SglPrice="38.000" Amount="228.760" FCCAmount="228.760" Taxrate="18" LogicalFPNumber="1" TankNumber="3" ArtNum="3" SaleNum="1"/>
        <Payment PAN="000000002117904490D" Amount="228.760" TenderCode="0" PayNum="1"/>
        <Employee Lastname="V KALYANI"/>
        <Vehicle LicensePlate="10K"/>
      </Sale>
      <Sale RcpNum="255" Amount="6650.000" Station="1" Customer="ZZZZZZ" Terminal="0">
        <Date Year="2011" Month="07" Day="12"/>
        <Time Hour="07" Minute="24" Second="00"/>
        <ArticleSale Quantity="175.000" SglPriceAsSold="38.000" SglPriceAsStored="38.000" SglPrice="38.000" Amount="6650.000" FCCAmount="6650.000" Taxrate="19" LogicalFPNumber="1" TankNumber="1" ArtNum="3" SaleNum="1"/>
        <Payment PAN="000000001885018677D" Amount="6650.000" TenderCode="0" PayNum="1"/>
      </Sale>
      <Sale RcpNum="152" Amount="3078.000" Station="1" Customer="000003" Terminal="1">
        <Date Year="2011" Month="07" Day="12"/>
        <Time Hour="07" Minute="27" Second="00"/>
        <ArticleSale Quantity="81.000" SglPriceAsSold="38.000" SglPriceAsStored="38.000" SglPrice="38.000" Amount="3078.000" FCCAmount="3078.000" Taxrate="18" LogicalFPNumber="1" TankNumber="3" ArtNum="3" SaleNum="1"/>
        <Payment PAN="000000002117928224D" Amount="3078.000" TenderCode="0" PayNum="1"/>
        <Employee Lastname="A MUNIYANDI"/>
        <Vehicle LicensePlate="10F"/>
      </Sale>
   </DocumentData>
</Transactions>
```

Thanks,

Comment: can you pls show us your XML?

Comment: Show the XML snippet and the Java code where the `NullPointerException` occurs.

Comment: U can try to generate an xsd for it(manually or automaticly). with that, u can make it automaticly and ignore null values also instead of handling exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using dom parser. If you are using `getElementsByTagName()` method, it will return null if no such element found. You better check for null for Employee tag.

Comment: how to check null for the employee tag?

Comment: NodeList n = e.getElementsByTagName(name); // here e refers to Sale node                                                           if(NodeList != null )                                                               // do whatever you want